# PHP page only sees 71 items in POST array value

Tags: php, ajax

I have quite an interesting issue. As you can see in the code below, I send 2 POST variables to my PHP page. One of the variables is a JSON array. If `unsyncedContacts.length` is < 71, it works as intended. As soon as we get over 71 items in the array, the PHP page will only recognize the first 71. I've watched the timeline in chrome as this is happening and the data is under a MB.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated as I am at a loss. There are no errors being thrown, and the 71 records that do manage to be sent between the pages are executed properly.

### JS

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/upsert_contacts.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    "contacts": unsyncedContacts,//JSON array
    "userInfo": localStorage.userInfo
  }
})
.done(function(data) {
 //do stuff here. i don't think its part of my issue
});
```

### PHP - upsert_contacts.php

```
set_time_limit(0);//set the time limit for each contact to prevent breaking.

//POST DATA
$currentUsersName = json_decode($_POST['userInfo']['usersName']);
$contacts         = $_POST['contacts'];
$aCount           = count($contacts);//returns 71 at MOST
```

I've tried stepping through the PHP with xdebugger and $aCount always returned 71 at most. As I said before, if it were say 50 items in $contacts, it'd work great. Once it hits 72, it gets weird

Edit: Someone asked in the comments, but deleted it: "Whats your server's max_input_vars set to?".

`max_input_vars 1000`

Comment: anything weird about your 71st/72nd contact's data?

Comment: Nope. That's the first thing I checked. Let's say I wanted to pass 142 through. It would execute fine for the first 71. Then I refresh and try again, it would do the next 71 just fine.

Comment: Have you checked the javascript side? Does 'unsyncedContacts' array has all the items?

Comment: Yes, the javascript side works just fine. It always has all the array items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the `max_input_vars`.

I had xdebug enabled in my dev environment and for some reason it did not show the PHP warning stating that I had exceeded the 1000 (the array i was passing was a JSON object with 14 properties).

14*71 = 994, meaning the next array item would go over the 1000 limit that I had set. To remedy this I created a .htaccess file with `php_value max_input_vars 20000` to ensure my code wont break again

Comment: Until you get over 1428 elements in your array. ;)

Comment: Lol!, That is a management issue at that point. Is there a way to remove the limit all together?

Comment: I've not checked but I assume (and hope!) that you can't (other than editing the source). You have no control over the vars as they come from a client, so limiting them is a good idea. If you have a need to submit an arbitrary number of values do it in small managable chunks via JavaScript.